# Refactor Large Switch Statement

Tags: c#, .net-core, switch-statement

I have written this method that "guesses" a correct font-awesome icon to apply to an expense based on user input from a form submission - validation is done before calling this method. If no conditions match, it returns a generic icon:

```
public static class IconService
{
    public static string GuessExpenseIcon(string input)
    {
        string expenseName = input.ToLower();
        string expenseIcon;

        switch (expenseName)
        {
            case string a when a.Contains("phone"):
            case string b when b.Contains("mobile"):
                expenseIcon = "fas fa-mobile-alt";
                break;

            case string a when a.Contains("rent"):
            case string b when b.Contains("mortgage"):
            case string c when c.Contains("house"):
            case string d when d.Contains("flat"):
            case string e when e.Contains("apartment"):
                expenseIcon = "fas fa-home";
                break;

            case string a when a.Contains("gas"):
            case string b when b.Contains("util"):
                expenseIcon = "fas fa-burn";
                break;

            case string a when a.Contains("electric"):
            case string b when b.Contains("power"):
                expenseIcon = "fas fa-bolt";
                break;

            case string a when a.Contains("petrol"):
            case string b when b.Contains("diesel"):
            case string c when c.Contains("fuel"):
                expenseIcon = "fas fa-gas-pump";
                break;

            case string a when a.Contains("food"):
            case string b when b.Contains("groceries"):
            case string c when c.Contains("eat"):
            case string d when d.Contains("take"):
                expenseIcon = "fas fa-utensils";
                break;

            case string a when a.Contains("water"):
                expenseIcon = "fas fa-shower";
                break;

            case string a when a.Contains("car"):
            case string b when b.Contains("van"):
                expenseIcon = "fas fa-car";
                break;

            case string a when a.Contains("internet"):
            case string b when b.Contains("network"):
                expenseIcon = "fas fa-wifi";
                break;

            case string a when a.Contains("spotify"):
                expenseIcon = "fab fa-spotify";
                break;

            case string a when a.Contains("bus"):
            case string b when b.Contains("coach"):
                expenseIcon = "fas fa-bus";
                break;

            case string a when a.Contains("charity"):
            case string b when b.Contains("donation"):
                expenseIcon = "fas fa-hand-holding-heart";
                break;

            case string a when a.Contains("aws"):
                expenseIcon = "fab fa-aws";
                break;

            default:
                expenseIcon = "fas fa-money-bill-alt";
                break;
        }

        return expenseIcon;
    }
}
```

My question is: is a switch statement this large the best way to achieve this?

I know I may just be prematurely optimizing as I haven't noticed negative performance but for some reason it just doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd define a Dictionary and use that:

```
public static class IconService
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _expenseIcons = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
        { "phone", "fa-mobile-alt" },
        { "mobile", "fa-mobile-alt" },
        { "rent", "fa-mobile-alt" },
        { "mortgage", "fa-mobile-alt" },
        { "house", "fa-mobile-alt" },
        { "flat", "fa-mobile-alt" },
        { "apartment", "fa-mobile-alt" }
        /* etc */
    };

    public static string GuessExpenseIcon(string input)
    {
        if (_expenseIcons.TryGetValue(input, out string expenseIcon)) // if the icon is found in the dictionary
        {
            return $"fas {expenseIcon}";
        }

        // default
        return "fas fa-money-bill-alt";
    }
}
```

You've said that you need to kind of guess it from a string, a naive tokenization (splitting by string) might work:

```
public static string GuessExpenseIcon(string input)
{
    string[] parts = input.Split();
    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        if (_expenseIcons.TryGetValue(part, out string expenseIcon)) // if the icon is found in the dictionary
        {
            return $"fas {expenseIcon}";
        }
    }
    // default
    return "fas fa-money-bill-alt";
}
```

I've used a case-insensitive string comparer for the dictionary key, so you don't need to do the `.ToLower()` bit. I've also taken the common "fas" part of the icon out from what we store in the dictionary, since every icon has it.

I don't think this is necessarily better than your `switch` statement, but it's more elegant solution, and it also opens up the possibility of changing how `_expenseIcons` is configured. For example, you could load it from a config file, etc.

In terms of efficiency, we're initialising the dictionary once for the lifetime of the application / appdomain. The [efficiency of lookups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) in the dictionary itself is close to O(1):

> Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` class is implemented as a hash table.

Comment: After testing this I realize that it doesn't meet some requirements that admittedly, I didn't specify. If a user inputs "phone bill" instead of "phone" then the default string will be returned as it is not checking whether or not "phone" is contained within the input anymore, only that a "phone" key exists in the dictionary.

Comment: @Beau In that case, what you're trying to do will probably never be particularly efficient since it involves a string search. The efficiency of dictionaries comes from the fact that they hash the key and then partition entries in a low-cost lookup structure by hash. It might be suitable to tokenize the input string (perhaps split by space) and then look up each individual word in the dictionary. I'm not sure if this will be faster though.

Comment: I've made an edit to demonstrate a test by simply tokenizing the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a list for each case

```
foreach (var str in new string[] { "phone","mobile" }) {
    if (expenseName.Contains(str)){
        expenseIcon = "fas fa-mobile-alt";
    }
}
```

It might also be worth to look into Lambda expressions, those have a shorter syntax in Java, but i am not sure how well this is supported in C#

Comment: I've corrected your code so that it's valid C# (you can't declare an array with `[ value, value ]`), and `Contains` has an uppercase C.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
class MatchPattern
{
    public string [] Patterns {get;set;}

    // This is to asume that you have more logic 
    // If all the logic of GetIcon is to return a simple string, you can
    // replace with 
    //  public string IconName {get;set;}
    // instead.
    public Func<string, string> GetIcon {get;set;}
}

public class IconService
{
    private MatchPatterns[] _patterns;
    public IconService()
    {
        _patterns=new []
        {
            new MatchPattern
            {
                Patterns=new[]{"phone", "mobile"},
                GetIcon=(x)=>"fas fa-mobile-alt"
            },
            new MatchPattern
            {
                Patterns=new[]{"rent", "mortgage", "house", "flat", "apartment"},
                GetIcon=(x)=>"fas fa-home"
            }
            , 
            // Here is more
        }
    }
    public static string GuessExpenseIcon(string input)
    {
        foreach(var pattern in _patterns)
        {
            if(pattern.Any(item=>input.contains(item))
            {
                return pattern.GetIcon.Invoke(input);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The use of Func is to cover the scenario that you still have some slightly different logic between different cases. If that is not the case, you can use a simply IconName instead of GetIcon Func.

```
class MatchPattern
{
    public string [] Patterns {get;set;}

    public string IconName {get;set;}
}
```